# C# DataView RowFilter, null value for DateTime column

Tags: c#, datetime, null, filtering, dataview

I'm trying to filter on null columns (I only want to show rows where the column is null), but the issue is I can't compare the column to a null, since the column is of DateTime value.

I get the following error

> System.Data.EvaluateException: Cannot
>   perform '=' operation on
>   System.DateTime and System.String.

This is my code for the filter

```
CourseID IN (" + courseIds + ") AND Isnull(DateBooked, 'Null Column') = 'Null Column'
```

DateBooked is the column with DateTime value.  Everything before the Isnull is functioning correctly.
Help please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't `isnull` always return a value of the same type as its first parameter?

Try `DateBooked IS NULL` instead of `Isnull(DateBooked, 'Null Column') = 'Null Column'`.

Comment: Oh man, I tried doing DateBooked = null before...  t-sql skipped in my mind for some reason lol.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, yes, the evils of the `= NULL` syntax. That one has bit me too a few times. Glad I could help.