# Excluding null values in DataView

Tags: c#, filter, filtering, dataview

In a column of my `DataTable` are null values.  When I create a `DataView` on this table, I would like filter out the null values. How do I do this?

I got my code working like this:

```
//get the cities and a view on the data
DataTable dtPlaatsen = client.getCities();
DataView dvPlaatsen = dtPlaatsen.DefaultView;

// filter and sort the view
dvPlaatsen.RowFilter= "Isnull(Plaatsnaam,'Null Column') <> 'Null Column'"; 
dvPlaatsen.Sort = "Plaatsnaam";


//attach the view as datasource
ddlCities.DataSource = dvPlaatsen;
ddlCities.DataTextField = "Plaatsnaam"; //the field to display to the user
ddlCities.DataValueField = "PlaatsId"; //the field which is send

ddlCities.DataBind();

ddlCities.SelectedIndex = 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this before the sort but whatever filter you wanna do, use the dataview row filter

```
          dvPlaatsen.RowFilter = "Plaatsnaam <> null"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
Isnull(Plaatsnaam, 'Null Column') != 'Null Column'
```

I just modified an accepted answer from a related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168112/c-sharp-dataview-rowfilter-null-value-for-datetime-column?rq=1).  Of course if it works you should thank [Michael Kjörling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486504/michael-kjorling) for the assistance.