# Syntax error : Missing Operand before 'IS' Operator

Tags: c#

I am using a Rowfilter to query a datatable that has the following columns:

1. USER_NAME(String)
2. USER_ID(INT)
3. USER_CODE(STRING)

My `Rowfilter` is as follows :

```
dv.RowFilter = UserName_ColumnName + " = '" + CurrentUserName + "' And " + UserID_ColumnName + " = " + CurrentID.ToString() + " And " + UserCode_ColumnName + " Is Null";
```

On Debugging this is the row filter that I got :

```
dv.RowFilter = USER_NAME = 'mike.sl' And USER_ID = 2753 And USER_CODE Is Null
```

However I am getting an exception which states :Missing operand before 'IS' operator.
I searched lot of sites and have tried many options, but none helped.

The strange thing is it works properly on one system, but on another system it keeps failing, though the code and the values remain the same.

Please help me in resolving this error.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Swati

Comment: It strongly suggests that UserCode_ColumnName is coming back empty on the one that fails.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @ BugFinder. It worked !!! I somehow had missed adding the proper reference for the UserCode_ColumnName because of which it was coming empty.

Comment: No worries - I'll add it as an answer so you can mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Strange, it shouldn't be working at all, as according to the documentation I found there is no `IS` for row filters... You can try to use the `ISNULL` function instead:

```
dv.RowFilter = UserName_ColumnName + " = '" + CurrentUserName + "' And " + 
               UserID_ColumnName + " = " + CurrentID.ToString() + " And " +
               "ISNULL("+ UserCode_ColumnName + ", '-') = '-'";
```

Reference: http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

Please make sure that the `UserCode_ColumnName` is not an empty string or `null`, as otherwise you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ Thorsten Dittmar. I tried that option but I got some exception stating invalid number of arguments in ISNULL. So I searched MSDN and got the correct usage, but that did not help either.

Comment: Also, in another site mentioned below they suggest using 'IS' in row filters. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168112/c-sharp-dataview-rowfilter-null-value-for-datetime-column

Comment: @SwatiDas I modified my code to fix the error. Are you really sure that you do get a value in `UserCode_ColumnName`? Because I think that user BugFinder may be on the right track, too.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I was not getting values for UserCode_ColumnName. So now I have fixed that and it's working now :)

Comment: @SwatiDas Then please upvote and accept BugFinder's answer, as he was right in the first place.

Comment: Oh yes, I did that already, but since I am a new member so my votes do not show up :|

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment.

The error suggests that the UserCode_ColumnName variable is empty at the call. How or why is going to be hidden in other code in your app, however, hunting that down will solve your issue.